# ClassPathHelper plugin not recognized by Luna

Tags: eclipse, plugins, windows-7-x64

I downloaded and installed [ClassPathHelper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) and set up Eclipse to start with the `-Xms64m`command line switch. However, I still can't see it in Eclipse's about dialog, nor can I find the class path view.

The plugin has 7 folders in form `classpathhelper.*` which are all located in the `plugins` directory, so that looks much like other plugins.

I have tried:

- starting eclipse from the command prompt to see error messages printed to console
- looking at the "Error Log" view. There are errors, but not regarding the classpath plugin
- looking at the "Console" view and other views, but there's nothing suitable

How can I find out what is wrong with the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These plugins are very old and are using the Eclipse 2.0 style plugin format which is no longer supported by Eclipse Luna by default.

You can install support for 2.0 style plugins using Help > Install New Software.

Select the 'Eclipse Project Updates' site (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4).

You will find 'Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support' in the 'Eclipse Tests, Examples and Extras' section.

But given the age of the plugins they may not work well on Luna.